# merging two dataframes and keep only the matching columns

Tags: r

(EDIT) I have two data frames with various columns. I want to concatenate them and only keep the columns that I want.

```
#this is the data
df1 = data.frame(Id = c(129,109), Product = c('nutella', 'crepes'), 
             sales= c(1000000, 200000), ratings = c(5,3), Company=c('a','b'))
df2 = data.frame(Id = c(154,198), Product = c('cheesecake', 'oreo'), 
             sales= c(150000, 3000000), Taxpaid = c(120, 3000), 
             Company=c('c','d'))


#Desired Output:

    Id     Product       
    129    nutella     
    109    crepes      
    154    cheesecake  
    198    oreo
```

Comment: `cols <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2));
rbind(df1[cols], df2[cols])
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an `intersect` of the columns of two datasets and `rbind` the datasets

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
rbind(df1[nm1], df2[nm1])
```